# Facebook - user's selected attending events data with FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I'm trying to get the name of a user's attending events with FQL, but I can't get true result. Is my SQL wrong or not possible to use?

**FQL:**

```
SELECT eid,name,start_time FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = USER_ID and rsvp_status='attending' and (eid=EID1 or eid=EID2 or eid=EID3) and start_time < START_TIME  ORDER BY start_time desc)
```

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by `true` result. What do you expect to get, and what you really get?

Comment: i said "true results" 'cuz user's attending events count and events count on fql result is not matching.
i found the problem. My fql on my answer successfully works. i saw some events have same id on my client's event database. this mean problem is solved... Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this instead:

```
SELECT name, venue, location, start_time FROM event WHERE eid IN (
  SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = "USER_ID_HERE" and rsvp_status="attending"
);
```

Comment: i have a event database with eid. i need to show logged user's attending events (not all attending events. just recorded events from database) on page. im trying to get results with loop, it works but it takes too much time.